# Doubled answer: separate+edit -- how to deal with this?

Tags: discussion, answers

How to deal with an answer, that is given by poster as [a separate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9874991/1469208), and is then made as [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/9526176/revisions) to [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9526176/1469208), to which it relates?

We end up with two nearly duplicate answers. How to deal with this situation?

Comment: I don't get the close votes here. Despite it being related to Stack Overflow in this case, it can happen anywhere. SO is just an example.

Comment: @nicael I guess it happens so infrequently that this should be on Meta Stack Overflow with a [meta-tag:specific-question] tag.

Comment: @Duncan Any particular reason, why it should be there? It can happen infrequently _anywhere within SE_. SO has nothing to do with this question, it is just example. However, after your comment and so many close votes, I clearly see, that not everyone understands this... Pity!

Comment: @trejder I'll try and explain better... I think this happens very infrequently and I suspect that whenever it happens, we need to look at the context of that specific instance. Therefore I doubt there is a generic answer that applies in all cases. Consequently, it probably is worth discussing each case individually on the relevant Meta with a [meta-tag:specific-question] tag. Note: I didn't vote to close, I'm just assuming this was the reason.

Comment: @Duncan Thanks for explanations, but I still don't follow you. First of all -- again -- it can happen anywhere, so discussing this on any particular meta isn't wise, IMHO. Second of all -- I don't think context has anything to do here. We have just two doubled answers and that's it, no matter, what these answers actually answer. And third of all -- I don't see, why a generic answer to this question can't be forge? For me this was so obvious (flag to delete duped, separate answer, since edit was incorporated to first one), that I was sure, I get immediate answer here.